# Segmented button with numeric value in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch application and I have a doubt with the next implementation, I have this code:

```
  {
    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
    cls : 'filterbar-segmented-button',
    items: [
      {
        text: x.util.I18n.getLabel('CustomerHeaderAll'),
        pressed: true
      },
      {
        text: x.util.I18n.getLabel('CustomerHeaderWithSurvey')
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am getting the label from the backend but I need to get the total value.

here Json API:

```
"CustomerHeaderAll" : "All {0}",
"CustomerHeaderWithSurvey": "With Survey {0}",
```

How should I implement the value (in between brackets) in the view? Now only I am displaying the label, but I need to concatenate both.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [tpl config in Ext.button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-tpl) and [set data config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-data) as initial display.

Call [Ext.button.setData()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-setData) to change displayed text.

For example:

```
{
    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
    cls : 'filterbar-segmented-button',
    items: [
      {
        data: {textVal: 1},
        tpl: "All {textVal}",
        pressed: true
      },
      {
        data: {suveyVal: 1},
        tpl: "With Survey {suveyVal}"
      }
    ]
  }
```